# Unable to use json.loads() on column of strings

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataset containing a column that has strings that I need to convert into a dictionary. I am able to convert each individual row into a dictionary but when I try to iterate over the entire column, it gives me a
`JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 45 (char 44)` error.

Each row in the column that needs to be converted to a dictionary looks like-

> '{"address_components": [{"long_name": "Bundall Road & Slatyer Avenue", "short_name": "Bundall Rd & Slatyer Ave", "types": ["intersection"]}, {"long_name": "Bundall", "short_name": "Bundall", "types": ["locality", "political"]}, {"long_name": "City of Gold Coast", "short_name": "Gold Coast", "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]}, {"long_name": "Queensland", "short_name": "QLD", "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]}, {"long_name": "Australia", "short_name": "AU", "types": ["country", "political"]}, {"long_name": "4217", "short_name": "4217", "types": ["postal_code"]}], "formatted_address": "Bundall Rd & Slatyer Ave, Bundall QLD 4217, Australia", "geometry": {"location": {"lat": -27.9976302, "lng": 153.4141172}, "location_type": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER", "viewport": {"northeast": {"lat": -27.9962812197085, "lng": 153.4154661802915}, "southwest": {"lat": -27.9989791802915, "lng": 153.4127682197085}}}, "partial_match": true, "place_id": "EjVCdW5kYWxsIFJkICYgU2xhdHllciBBdmUsIEJ1bmRhbGwgUUxEIDQyMTcsIEF1c3RyYWxpYSJmImQKFAoSCeXEHjVABZFrEWe7h22UE8tZEhQKEgnlxB41QAWRaxFnu4dtlBPLWRoUChIJL6kK0T0FkWsR6nklFR-GhrUaFAoSCSPmlM5HBZFrEQEWnceuQwCyIgoNkuZP7xX0InFb", "types": ["intersection"], "rca_extended_properties": {"geocode": {"quality_id": 5, "quality_tx": "Postal Code"}, "distanceInMeters": "none", "displayCity_tx": "Gold Coast", "displayCityNameOrigin_id": 8, "searchParcels": false}, "reverse_geocode": {"adminLevel2_id": 12489, "adminLevel2_tx": "Gold Coast (C)", "adminLevel2Type_tx": "Local_Gov_Area", "adminLevel2_display_city_name_fg": false, "adminLevel1_id": 1504, "adminLevel1_tx": "Queensland", "adminLevel1Type_tx": "States", "adminLevel1_display_city_name_fg": false, "adminLevel0_id": 13, "adminLevel0_tx": "Australia", "adminLevel0_display_city_name_fg": false, "postalCode_id": 39319, "postalCode_tx": "4217", "city_id": 166830, "city_tx": "Gold Coast", "city_display_city_name_fg": true, "subMarket_id": 1460, "subMarket_tx": "Gold Coast", "market_id": 611, "market_tx": "Gold Coast", "metro_id": 94, "metro_tx": "Gold Coast", "region_id": 288, "region_tx": "Queensland", "subTheatre_id": 2, "subTheatre_tx": "Australia", "theatre_id": 2, "theatre_tx": "Australia - NZ", "continent_id": 4, "continent_tx": "Pacific", "zone_id": 2, "zone_tx": "AsiaPac", "cbd_fg": false}}'>

This mess basically needs to be converted to a dictionary, and when I run

`json.loads(df["column"][0])`

it returns a dictionary. So why does it throw an error when I try to iterate over the whole column using

`df["column"] = df["column"].apply(json.loads)`

I would like each row to be converted to a dictionary using json.loads()

Please help.

​

Comment: The first thing to check would be if `json.loads(df["column"][i])` works for all expected values of `i`.

Comment: probably because somewhere you have a sting that isn't valid json. Just because *the first* item in the series is valid JSON doesn't mean the rest have to be. Is there any particular reason you are using pandas to begin with?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga fair point, but the JSONDecodeError: is throwing out an error in line 1. When I'm able to get the dict output for that line. (?)

Comment: @AamashHaroon what? That has *nothing* to do with `df["column"][0]`. how would the JSON decoder even know?

Comment: So, it figure out which is the offending item in the column, loop over it and try-catch the error, and in the except, capture the index

Comment: @chepner I have over 30k rows, is there an efficient way to check that?

Comment: `for i, s in enumerate(df["column"]): ...` and then put the try-except in there.